# First element from array in Step functions Pass state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have this strange problem with AWS step functions Pass state.

I currently send the following JSON to a Pass state

```
[
  [
    {
      "key": "value"
    }
  ]
]
```

I need to remove the top array and send only the array and object to the next step.

```
      [
        {
          "key": "value"
        }
      ]
```

When I try with `ResultPath: "$[0]` it is added an extra array on top instead.
When I try with `Params: { "$": "$[0]" }` it considers the following as static input and prints as is.

Is there a way I can achieve the desired output? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

The [**OutputPath**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-outputpath.html) field can be used here to filter your JSON. It allows you to select a specific part of your output, and pass only that data on to the next state. The **[ResultPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html)** field is used to specify the path in the input to write your output. Since you specified "$[0]", your output was written to index 0 of an array.

We understand these fields can be quite tricky to become familiar with, and we are working on some new ways to help smooth out this process for our customers!

Comment: thanks, I just ran into this! I, too, was trying to use ResultPath and ResultSelector.